# Excel formula, if cell contains A, B or C, equal either 1,2 or 3

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im trying to create a formula for categorize owners in excel. we have owners in W and the owner group os either SOFT FM, HARD FM or Office support.

see attachment. cant get this formula to work.

[image]

Comment: What should your code do, and what does it *currently* do?  Are `HARDFM`, `SOFTFM` and `OFFICE SUPPORT` range/object references?  If so, `OFFICE SUPPORT` should not have a space - delete it or use an underscore.  If these are supposed to be text instead, then **they need to be in quotes!**

Comment: We have an excel report there we get owners from the software, there are a lot of different types of owners. They very from soft_vending, soft_cleaning and so on. can be Hard_elec&fire or hard_hvac as well in column W. but i want to categorize these to only soft, hard or office. in column X. So if it says Soft_cleaning in W i want it to say SOFT FM in column X and if it says Hard_elec&fire in W i want it to say HARD FM in X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function does not recognize the wildcards, you can use the `SEARCH` function instead of `w6="*hard*"`. And, of course, strings must be in quotes, as @Chronocidal says.

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("hard",W6))),"HARD FM",IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("soft",W6))),"SOFT FM",IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("OFFICE",W6))),"OFFICE SUPPORT","NA")))
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. i had to change , to ; tho :)

Comment: Is it possible to add more functions? if i want to add one or to more?

Comment: I mean if i want A,B,C,D,E to equal 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 is that possible?

Comment: Of course, you just need to add an additional IF

However, if the number of conditions becomes large, better look at shrivallabha.redij or Justyn MK's solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `COUNTIF` and nest it into `IF` to get the desired result.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(W6, "*HARD*") > 0, "HARD FM", IF(COUNTIF(W6, "*SOFT*") > 0, "SOFT FM", IF(COUNTIF(W6, "*OFFICE*") > 0, "OFFICE SUPPORT", "NA")))
```

Note: It will work in the order of if statement used. Like if there is a string `SOFTHARD`, then it will display result `HARD FM`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use following construct

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH({"HARD","SOFT","OFFICE"},W6,1),{"HARD FM","SOFT FM","OFFICE SUPPORT"}),"NA")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one more solution - combine `CHOOSE` and `MATCH` functions:

```
=IFERROR(CHOOSE(MATCH(1,COUNTIF(W6,{"*hard*";"*soft*";"*office*"}),0),"HARDFM","SOFTFM","OFFICE SUPPORT"),"NA")
```

The result:

[image]